# Dúvida com erro "Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory" Java

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly

Eu recebi as fontes e após fazer as configurações do servidor, banco de dados etc, estou com este problema na compilação. Agradeço se alguém puder indicar uma direção na solução.

> ```
> [2017-09-11 10:12:46,640] Artifact multlevel-web:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
> [2017-09-11 10:12:46,640] Artifact multlevel-web:war: java.lang.Exception:
>  {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"multlevel.war#primary\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"multlevel.war#primary\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
> [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>  Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>     Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [tb_cdm]"},"WFLYCTL0412:
>  Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"multlevel.war#primary\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
> ```

Comment: Isso não é problema de compilação. Esse `missing table [tb_cdm]` dá a entender que o Wildfly esperava encontrar a tabela `tb_cdm` no PostgreSQL, mas essa tabela não está lá.

Comment: Correto Victor, realmente não existe mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é problema de compilação.

Esse `missing table [tb_cdm]` indica que o Wildfly esperava encontrar a tabela `tb_cdm` no PostgreSQL, mas essa tabela não está lá.